# Problem with uploading large files to google cloud storage with nest.js

Tags: reactjs, nestjs, google-cloud-storage

I have problems with uploading files over 64mb. My stack is React and nest.js. I want to programmatically add files to google cloud storage bucket. Since I am uploading files larger than 32mb, I should use createWriteStream function. Uploading files below approximately 64mb gives me no problem, but when I go over 64mb, it just doesn't do anything. I noticed that looking at logs of my gae application, when I upload small files it makes two requests to server: OPTIONS and PATCH request, whilst uploading bigger files, makes only OPTIONS request. What is the issue here and how can I get rid of such behavioiur?

This is my backend code of how I process the file:

```js
  @Patch(':id/audio')
  @Roles(Role.MOD, Role.ADMIN)
  @UseInterceptors(
    FileInterceptor('audio', {
      fileFilter: audioFileFilter,
    }),
  )
  async addAudio(
    @Req() req: Express.Request,
    @UploadedFile() audio: Express.Multer.File,
  ) {
    return await this.bookService.uploadFile(req, audio, 'audio');
  }
```

```
async uploadFile(
    req,
    file: Express.Multer.File,
    type: 'audio' | 'lyrics',
  ): Promise<any> {
    const id = req.params['id'];
    const lang = req.body['language'];
    let fullName: string;
    if (type === 'audio') {
      const voice_id = req.body['voice_id'];
      const audioType = req.body['type'];
      fullName =
        this.setDestination(id, lang) +
        this.audioFileName(voice_id, audioType, file);
    } else {
      fullName = this.setDestination(id, lang) + this.lyricsFileName(file);
    }
    const blob = this.bucket.file(fullName);
    if (await blob.exists()) {
      await this.removeFile(fullName);
    }
    let uploadedBytes = 0;
    const blobStream = blob.createWriteStream({
      resumable: false,
    });

    blobStream.on('data', (chunk) => {
      uploadedBytes += chunk.length;
      const progress = (uploadedBytes / file.size) * 100;
      console.log(`Progress: ${progress.toFixed(2)}%`);
    });
    blobStream.on('error', (error) => console.log(error));
    blobStream.on('finish', async () => {
      try {
        await this.bucket.file(fullName).makePublic();
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
      }
    });

    blobStream.end(file.buffer);
    return {
      publicUrl: `https://storage.googleapis.com/${this.bucket.name}/${fullName}`,
    };
  }
```

This is how I send the audio on front:

```
async function addAudio(
  this: Server,
  id: string,
  token: string,
  audio: ServerDto.AddAudio
) {
  let config = {
    headers: {
      "x-access-token": token,
      "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
    },
    onUploadProgress: (progressEvent: any) => {
      const percentCompleted = Math.round(
        (progressEvent.loaded * 100) / progressEvent.total
      );
      console.log(`Upload progress: ${percentCompleted}%`);
    },
  };
  const { data } = await axios.patch(
    `${this.baseUrl}/books/${id}/audio`,
    audio,
    config
  );
  return data;
}
```

Comment: Please add some code snippet of what you have tried so far

Comment: Do you have errors?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere no, I don't get anything. just OPTIONS request that does nothing

Comment: Your browser will send a preflight OPTIONS request. Your service must handle and reply to it. Else, I fear that the browser will upload anything if OPTIONS is not answered.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere yeah, but I don't have to do that in other api endpoints... why do I need this here? I think that the problem is with google and uploading big files. Maybe it is limited because I am on free tier?